# "ReferenceError: addIndent is not defined"

Tags: json

This `json` is valid and is working fine in postman but when I try to beautify this `json` [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer#) it is saying that

> ReferenceError: addIndent is not defined

```
{
    "requestinfo": 
    {
        "services": [
        {
            "id": "27",
            "sub_id1": "",
            "sub_id2": "",
            "discount": "0",
            "price": "999"

        }],
        "companyId": "329",
        "userId": "274",
        "gst": "180",
        "gstPer": "18",
        "subTotal": "999",
        "grandTotal": "1178.82"
    }
}
```

Comment: if you just want to beautify the json, just go to https://jsonlint.com, then validate, you can check also if there's an error... and try pasting it in notepad++ or whatever editor you can check if there are unicode characters included in your json,

Comment: now it is working fine

Comment: yeah it's just probably some unicode characters that was created when you beautified the json